# C++ metaprogramming with templates versus inlining

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Is it worth to write code like the following to copy array elements:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<int START, int N> 
struct Repeat { 
  static void copy (int * x, int * y) {
   x[START+N-1] = y[START+N-1];
   Repeat<START, N-1>::copy(x,y);
  }
};

template<int START> 
struct Repeat<START, 0> { 
  static void copy (int * x, int * y) {
   x[START] = y[START];
  }
};



int main () {


   int a[10];
   int b[10];

             // initialize
   for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
     b[i] = 113 + i;
     a[i] = 0;
   }

            // do the copy (starting at 2, 4 elements)
  Repeat<2,4>::copy(a,b);

             // show
   for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
   cout << a[i] << endl;
   }

} // ()
```

or is it better to use a inlined function?

A first drawback is that you can't use variables in the template.

Comment: You should just use `std::copy`. You can be almost sure that *that* utilizes some metaprogramming techniques to forward copying between int arrays to memmove.

Comment: Christ, I'd rather spend 10 lifetimes programming prolog, than spend anymore time looking at C++ compile time metaprogramming :(. If you gotta copy something, you gotta copy it, you can't get away from it by thinking you can do it at compile time just because you think you can identify the variables that will be copied

Comment: @Hassan: Depending on the datatypes and alignment, different strategies for copying may be suitable though, and it might be possible to speed the operation up dramatically. It is not "just a copy". (But as @UncleBens says, `std::copy` already does this)

Comment: This is very helpful. It's the only solution I have seen where you can specify how much to unroll in code. I looked at the assembly output in GCC with Repeat<0,100> and it unrolled it 100 times. Despite what many people claim, loop unrolling can still be useful for performance. It's easy to beat `memcpy` or `std::copy` if you know what you're doing. But unrolling is more useful in other cases such as z[i] = x[i] + y[i].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not better. First of all, it's not really compile time, since you make function calls here. If you are lucky, the compiler will inline these and end up with a loop you could have written yourself with much less amount of code (or just by using `std::copy`).

Comment: This is just not true. The recursion is compile-time, there is no runtime recursion here. Each function is of a different class, and is just not the same function. What would say would be true for Java though!

Comment: @PierreBdr, it is true that a different function is involved each time. But these are function calls done at runtime, and the effect is as if you would call the same function in a recursive manner (as opposed to *true* compile time recursion ala' `static int const value = Class<N-1>::value + 1;`). The only difference is that the end condition can be evaluated at compile time. But so can the condition of an equivalent loop.

Comment: @PierreBdr, i've removed the part that stated that this is a recursive function, as i agree with you that was misleading.

Comment: I read the assembler code generated and seems something like:

copy_first: mov ...
            mov ...
           call copy_second

copy_second: mov ...
            mov ...
            call copy_third

copy_third: mov ...
           mov....

The code will do the same just removing the calls !

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, I looked at the assembly output from the code in the OPs question in GCC. It unrolls the loop as desired. This is the best solution I have seen for auto-unrolling.

Answer (score 1):

General rule:  Use templates for things known at compile time, use inlining for things known at run time.  If you don't know the size of your array at compile time, then don't be using templates for it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this. Templates were invented for different purpose, not for calculations, although you can do it. First you can't use variables, second templates will produce vast of unused structures at compilation, and third is: use `for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) b[i] = a[i];`

Comment: Yes, templates were invented for different purpose, but you just can't imagen how many books writte and e-ink used for that second non-intendend use !

Comment: Yep, don't make claims about templates that you cannot substantiate.

Answer (score 0):

That's better because you control and enforce the loop unrolling by yourself.

A loop can be unrolled by the compiler depending on optimizing options...

The fact that copying with `copy` is almost the best is not a good general answer because the loop unrolling can be done whatever is the computation done inside...