# What are the differences between `typename std::remove_reference<T>` and `constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>`?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, std, typename

As per the documentation(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), there are two kinds of constructors for `std::move<T>`, which are posted below.

What are the differences between these constructors?
What confused me most is that why there needs the keyword(`typename`) in the second constructor.

I am a novice in C++. I would be thankful for any hint on this question.

```
template< class T >
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t ) noexcept; (since C++11)(until C++14)

template< class T >
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t ) noexcept;  (since C++14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] there are two kinds of constructors for `std::move<T>`...

No, they are not constructors, rather function signatures of `std::move`. One is prior to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)(i.e. since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) and the second one since C++14.

In the second one the [specifier `constexpr` is used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), meaning

> `constexpr` - specifies that **the value of a variable or function can**
>   **appear in constant expressions**

read more here:[What are 'constexpr' useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473795/what-are-constexpr-useful-for)

---

> What confused me most is that why there needs the keyword(`typename`) in
>   the second constructor.

As per the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference), there is a helper type for `std::remove_reference`, since [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)

```
template< class T >
using remove_reference_t = typename remove_reference<T>::type;  (since C++14)
```

therefore in the second one, it could have been

```
template< class T >
constexpr std::remove_reference_t<T>&& move( T&& t ) noexcept;
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Why the former function signature does not need the keyword `typename`?Thank you.

Comment: @sunshilong369 The resultant type of traits `std::remove_reference` depends on the template type `T`, which needed to be mentioned to the compiler by `typename` keyword. See more examples here: [When is the “typename” keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary)

Comment: You see, there is `std::remove_reference` in former function signature, too.So why there is no need to put `typename` before it?

Comment: Sorry.My eyes deceive me.There are typename keywords in both of them indeed.My heart is full of thanks.